# How can I make round text input in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Consider:

[image: This is my output image]

I have created a custom rounded text input box using Kivy/KivyMD. The text input box has a rounded background, and I've added canvas instructions to achieve this effect. However, I'm facing two specific issues:

1.**Inability to Type:** When I interact with the rounded text input, I cannot type any text into it. It appears to be unresponsive to keyboard input.

2.**Text Input Behind Round Rectangle:** Additionally, the text input appears to be positioned behind the round rectangle. I want the text input to be in the foreground, allowing me to enter text while still retaining the rounded background.

**My Kivy code**

```
  MDFloatLayout:

    orientation: "vertical"

    size: root.width,root.height

    MDCard:

        size_hint: (None,None)

        size: (650,300)

        pos_hint:{"center_x" : 0.5 , "center_y": 0.5}

        MDBoxLayout:

            canvas.before:

                Rectangle:

                    source:"img/gradient.png"

                    size: self.size

                    pos: self.pos

            TextInput:
                hint_text: "text"

                hint_text_color: 0,0,0,1

                foreground_color:0,0,0,1

                background_color: 1,1,1,1

                multiline: False

                size_hint: (None,None)

                width: 500

                height: 30

                pos_hint:{"center_y": 0.90}

                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 1,1,1,1[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5bsJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5bsJ.png)

                    RoundedRectangle:
                        size: self.size

                        pos: self.pos

                        radius: 10,
```

What I tried:

I attempted to create a custom KivyMD text input widget with rounded corners by adding canvas instructions for a rounded background. I followed the guidance I found in the Kivy documentation and some online tutorials.

What I was expecting:

I expected to see a rounded text input box where I could type text. The rounded background should have a transparent or white fill, and the text input should be visible and functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the canvas instructions that are used for the `TextInput` by defining your own custom widget that is based on `TextInput`. For example:

```
<-MyTI@TextInput>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [10, 10, 10, 10]
        Color:
            rgba:
                self.disabled_foreground_color if self.disabled else (self.hint_text_color if not self.text else self.foreground_color)
```

The above defines a `MyTI` widget that is a `TextInput` with rounded corners. The `-` means that the existing `kv` rules for `TextInput` should be ignored. This is a somewhat simplified version of the `kv` rules for a `TextInput`, so there may be some capabilities that are not supported.